# JDialog does not close on 'X' button click

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have written an application that has one main window and multiple dialogs, however one of these dialogs does not close when the user clicks the 'X' button at the top right corner. There is an OK button in the dialog which closes it correctly, so it's not a huge issue. Can anyone suggest why it's not working?

Comment: Did you change its default close operation? Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help.

Comment: It's set to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE

Comment: If you can't find why it does not work, I can only encourage you to post some code and ideally, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I can't post the code as is because it's for work, if I can't figure it out I may copy it to a new file and strip out all the business logic and see if I can reproduce it

Comment: you read that link provided by @GuillaumePolet, didn't you? So I understand how _for work_ could be problem ...

Comment: @slicedPan read the article on [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), it actually advices you to remove anything not related to your problem. Moreover, this process of narrowing down your problem to a short example code is likely to guide you to find the source of your problem

Comment: Yeah I am familiar with the idea, just stripping out the unnecessary code now

Comment: FFFUUUUU, figured it out in the process, I had overridden dispose and hadn't called super.dispose()

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing such a line: setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE); in the dialog class?

Comment: Hmmm, this seems to work, but I don't understand why. All my other dialogs are set to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE and they work fine.